# Prime divisors of $a^p +1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p>2$ be a prime number and $a>1$. If $p_k|a^p+1$, but $p_k\nmid a+1$, where $p_k> 2$ is also prime, show that $p_k=2np+1$.

Comment: Formatting note: "\nmid" looks a lot better than "\not |".  As in $a\nmid b$ looks better than $a\not | b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it just now. Kind of tricky so I will write the answer out.

Suppouse $p_k|a^p+1$ This implies that $a^p\equiv -1 \mod (p_k)\Rightarrow a^{2p}\equiv 1 \mod (p_k)$.

$gcd(a,p_k)=1$, because $p_k|a^p-1$, and if $p_k|a$ it would also divide $-1$. Thus, By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{p_k-1}\equiv 1 \mod(p_k)$. This implies that:

$$a^{2p}\equiv a^{p_k-1}\equiv 1 \mod (p_k)$$

Using Bezout's identity is is easy to show that $gcd(p_k-1,2p)$ is such that:

$$a^{gcd(p_k-1,2p)} \equiv 1 \mod (p_k)$$

If $gcd(p_k-1,2p)=1\Rightarrow a\equiv 1 \mod(p_k)\Rightarrow a^p \equiv 1 \mod(p_k)$. Contradiction! Similarly, if $gcd(p_k-1,2p)=p$, $a^p\equiv 1$, another contradiction.

The only possibilites left are   $gcd(p_k-1,2p)=2$ or $gcd(p_k-1,2p)=2p$. If the first occurs, $a^2\equiv 1 \mod (p_k)$ and $a\equiv\pm1$. Neither of these possibilites can be true.

Thus $gcd(p_k-1,2p)=2p$ which yields $p_k-1=2pn$.